# Как получить все атрибуты элемента в selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Вопрос в теме.

Через метод [get_attribute(name)](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) можно получить значения атрибута, но нужно знать его название, поэтому метод не подходит.

---

В качестве примера для опробования предлагаю вывести у элемента **input_el** все атрибуты:

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/')

input_el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.s-input__search')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решением может быть через [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), используя метод [execute_script(script, *args)](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
def get_attributes(driver, element) -> dict:
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        let attr = arguments[0].attributes;
        let items = {}; 
        for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
            items[attr[i].name] = attr[i].value;
        }
        return items;
        """,
        element
    )
```

[Весь код](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/068def89127f101658b18e8e4ecc4aa07d920acb/selenium__examples/get_attributes.py#L11):

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver


def get_attributes(driver, element) -> dict:
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        let attr = arguments[0].attributes;
        let items = {}; 
        for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
            items[attr[i].name] = attr[i].value;
        }
        return items;
        """,
        element
    )


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/')

input_el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.s-input__search')
attrs = get_attributes(driver, input_el)
print(attrs)
# {'aria-controls': 'top-search', 'aria-label': 'Поиск', 'autocomplete': 'off',
#  'class': 's-input s-input__search js-search-field ', 'data-action': 'focus->s-popover#show',
#  'data-controller': 's-popover', 'data-s-popover-placement': 'bottom-start', 'maxlength': '240',
#  'name': 'q', 'placeholder': 'Поиск...', 'type': 'text', 'value': ''}

driver.quit()
```